# ActionListener implementation in neighboring class

Tags: java, swing, class, listener, actionlistener

I think that writing listeners in the same class is not OOP-way. So, I try to write listener in another file.

Code that works is:

```
class MyPanel extends JPanel{
 private String tString = "Test String";
 private JLabel tLabel;
 public MyPanel(){
    tLabel = new JLabel("Label");
    JButton tButton = new JButton("Click me");

    tButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){   
    public void ActionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
     tLabel.setText(tString);
    }
   });
}
```

But when I write listener in separated file:

```
public class MyListener implements ActionListener{
 copy code here
}
```

and change

```
tButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
```

to

```
tButton.addActionListener(new MyListener());
```

it doesn't work.
Of course i have tried different combinations.

For example, sending "this" to listener's constructor and calling methods from received
 object in listener's class.

Error:

```
MyListener: cannot find symbol "tLabel"
```

Comment: Can you post more details about how "it doesn't work" please?

Comment: public void ActionPerformed should be public void actionPerformed

Comment: Dan, this typo I did  here, in code all is ok.

Comment: Brian, I updated my question.

Comment: Why do you think this was not OOP-way?

Comment: May be I expressed wrong. In any case, classes must be separated as much as possible. Just my opinion :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you for editing your answer :)

It appears you're trying to access the `tLabel` variable from your new listener, but it's not accessible as it may be declared `private`. The same thing will probably also happen with `tString`. Try this:

```
public class MyListener implements ActionListener{

    private MyPanel myPanel;

    public MyListener(MyPanel myPanel) {
        this.myPanel = myPanel;
    }

    public void ActionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        myPanel.getTLabel().setText(myPanel.getTString());
    }
}
```

And add a getter for each of `tString` and `tLabel` to `MyPanel`:

```
public class MyPanel extends JPanel {

    // ...

    public String getTString() {
        return tString;
    }

    public JLabel getTLabel() {
        return tLabel;
    }
}
```

When you can't access a private field, generally you add a `public` "getter" which returns that field instead of changing the access of the field itself. Convention is that if, for example, the field is a `String` and is named `myField`, the getter is named `getMyField`. Like this, you can also add setters to set that variable. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1568091/why-use-getters-and-setters) for more on getters and setters.

Comment: It's also worth noting that not having a setter is also acceptable. This is one way [immutable objects](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/immutable.html) can be created.

Comment: Thank you! Just now I discovered, that in my listener's constructor param was JPanel but not MyPanel :D

Answer (score 1):

Your `MyListener` class has to have a constructor.  You pass "this" and whatever other parameters you need in the `MyListener` class constructor.

Here's an example from a project of mine.

```
package com.ggl.project.planner.controller;

import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import com.ggl.project.planner.model.Planner;
import com.ggl.project.planner.model.Project;
import com.ggl.project.planner.view.CreateUpdateProjectDialog;
import com.ggl.project.planner.view.ProjectPlannerFrame;

public class CreateProjectActionListener implements ActionListener {

    protected Planner planner;

    protected Project project;

    protected ProjectPlannerFrame frame;

    public CreateProjectActionListener(ProjectPlannerFrame frame,
            Planner planner, Project project) {
        this.frame = frame;
        this.planner = planner;
        this.project = project;
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
        CreateUpdateProjectDialog dialog = 
                new CreateUpdateProjectDialog(frame, project, true);
        if (dialog.isOkPressed()) {
            planner.setProjectOpen(true);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Or you mean I have to pass every object from panel that I want to change? May be it works, I will try.

But how to be, if i want to get the whole panel? For example to call her method?

Comment: @Danila: I pass (JPanel) "this" all the time.  I usually call it "panel" in the listener.  You would have methods in the JPanel class that the listener class can execute.  For example, panel.setButton3Text(text);

Answer (score 1):

Your `MyListener` class has no reference to the `tLabel` variable.

You can either set it through the constructor or pass the `MyPanel` reference to the `MyListener` and have a method in `MyPanel` that does the needed stuff on the `JLabel` and can be called from `MyListener`.

Comment: Thank you. But how to pass MyPanel to MeListener? I tried "this", it doesn't work.